# How to hide panel on SlidingPaneLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingpanelayout

I have this XML view that works with SlidingPaneLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/overview_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey50"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <de.timroes.android.listview.EnhancedListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey50"
        android:divider="@color/black12"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/selected_option"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And looks like this:

[image]

But what I want is to "hide" this piece of pane that is on the right side. But I search for examples, and found someones like: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial-2.html

But I'm not able to make it desappear. How can I achive it?

Comment: `slidingPaneLayout.closePane();` use this line to close

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, thanks... I thing I missunderstood "who" is the "principal" panel...  ^^